# JSF 1.2, Is there any utility to learn How it was working?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm asking this question as a new in Java EE

I know that JSF 2.0 (and this year JSF 2.2) had made JSF 1.2 more than obsolete !
But I was asking myself if knowing how JSF 1.2 was working, could help me to understand more easily how JSF 2.0 works, of if this could be of any other utility ! 
Should I read some of it or is it useless ?

In that case I could go straight to JSF 2.0 (or 2.2 ?)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it makes no sense to learn JSF 1.2 because you will only learn how to solve problems, which don't exist anymore with JSF 2 and JSF 2.2.

JSF 1.2 is not easier to understand than JSF 2 and thus it won't help you learning about JSF 2.

The only case it will be useful is when you are going to have to use the old JSF 1.2 in a project, but this gets more and more unlikely.

JSF 2.2 is still pretty new and not that widely used and mostly an extension to JSF 2.1 so it still makes sense to learn and use JSF 2.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you start with JSF 2.0 or 2.2 right away. It defently makes you understand more of a framework if you know previous versions but note that this know-how oftenly results in "oh wow this xy feature is now tousand times easier to use because all the complex stuff is made behind scenes".

I for example have a pretty good understanding of how Java changed from version 1.3 to current 7 (1.7) because i started to learn Java back the time it was in version 1.3. That time some language features changed, some came plus to the existing ones and others have not made it into the current release.

But if i would have to learn Java now and this would be day 1 of my learning i would never ever start with 1.3 again and make the same way up to version 7.

Back to your question: It depends on you, if you want to learn the history of the framework and see how things were made easier from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 feel free to do so but if you want to use JSF as a framework "just" to write business code id start with 2.0/ 2.2 right away.